# Reduce Dataset with FSelector in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataset, feature-selection

I'm new to R and I'd like to use it to perform Feature Selection on a dataset I have. I've found the FSelector package. I had a look at the manual but I have some doubts.

```
data(iris)
weights <- relief(Species~., iris, neighbours.count = 5, sample.size = 20)
subset <- cutoff.k(weights, 2)
f <- as.simple.formula(subset, "Species")
```

This example calculate the importance of each variable using Relief method. The last line creates a formula as: "class = feature1 + feature2 + ... +featureN". Now, given the subset of selected feature (a char array), how can I create a new dataset, from iris, which contains only those variables (i.e. a matrix with 2 columns)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you can just take a subset of iris using the results from `cutoff.k`, since that returns a vector with the names of the variables you want to keep:

```
newdata <-  iris[,cutoff.k(weights, 2)]
```

Here the `[]` command is used to get a subset of iris, in this case only the columns with the names in the result from `cutoff.k` (rows/columns are indicated as follows: `[rows,columns]`) .

To get a `matrix` instead of a `data.frame`: `as.matrix(iris[,cutoff.k(weights, 2)])`